# What is the equivalent of reduce in nim?

Tags: nim-lang

Is there a built-in `proc` which is equivalent to Python `reduce` or Javascript `Array.reduce`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are templates `foldl` and `foldr` in the `sequtils` module. Example:

```
import sequtils

proc factorial(n: int): int =
  foldl(1..n, a * b, 1)

echo factorial(10)
```

As templates, they do not take proc arguments, but inline expressions, where `a` and `b` are the operands. The template works for any sort of collection that has an `items` iterator, such as arrays, sequences, or ranges (as in the above example).

Comment: The fact that I can't use an anonymous `proc` as an argument but only an inline expression with operands does make nim much less functional-programming-friendly, doesn't it?

Comment: Well your inline expression can be `doSomething(a, b)` or even `somethingElse(b, 10, a+b, nested(b))`. Basically what it does is to stamp out whatever it is you put there into the body of the loop that it creates. This means you can use anything there, not only procedures with a certain signature. To achieve the same thing in Python you would need to use a wrapper function, but function calls aren't free so you will be adding overhead, this is both easier and more efficient. I'd say Nim is actually more functional friendly, just take a look at e.g. https://github.com/zero-functional

Comment: @PMunch you can't really be functional-friendly if you're not using functions  e.g., in a functional-friendly `foldl` you could do this: `foldl(1..n, `*`, 1)`.